# how to solve Django url patterns not working

Tags: python, django

I added path('int:pk/',...) in **urls.py**
and access 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1'

the result was

'page not found(404)'
Using the URLconf defined in doit.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. blog <int:pk>/
2. blog
3. admin/

The current path, blog/1, didn’t match any of these.

also, I made 3 pk contents

please help me I suffered for a long time.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', views.PostDetail.as_view()),
    path('', views.PostList.as_view()),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()

    created_at = models.DateTimeField()


    def __str__(self):
        return f'[{self.pk}]{self.title}'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post 


class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    ordering = '-pk'

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

**post_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Blog</h1>

{% for p in post_list %}
    <hr/>
    <h2> {{ p.title }} </h2>
    <p> {{ p.content }}</p>
    <h4> {{ p.created_at }} </h4> 

{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**post_detail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>

    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> {{ post.title }} - Blog </title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
    </nav>

    <h1> {{ post.title }} </h1>
    <h4> {{ post.created_at }} </h4>
    <p> {{ post.content }} </p>
    <hr/>

    <h3> ... </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably there are no rows with pk=1?

Comment: u have to render html file in your views.py

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, please

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view()),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you architected your project, but I'm assuming that you have created a separate urls.py file inside your app, if you did so, you are doing some things wrong in the code that you provided in this question. You are not declaring the `app_name` in your urls.py file, this makes it really hard for you to create links for your pages later on when you are expanding your project, and also makes it impossible for you to access pages, I'm going to give you some code, but make sure that you read it, and adapt it to your project.

This should be your urls.py in the project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('your_app_name.urls'))
]
```

After doing that, you should create an urls.py file inside your app folder, and make it look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = "your_app_name"

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='post_list'),
]
```

Note that I changed the way that you are importing the views, this way you don't need to write `views.PostDetail.as_view()`, you can just call it by the class name. I also added a name for each URL pattern, with this you can create links way easier like I mentioned before, you create an a tag in HTML that will look like that:

```
<a href='{% url 'your_app_name:post_list %}'>Blog</a>
```

By applying those changes to your code, it will probably work fine, but if it doesn't, feel free to contact me. Also try to learn about function based views in Django, they are better to use, since with class based views, you break the DRY(don't repeat yourself) concept of Django.